# A query to summarize data in sub-tree?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My data fits a tree form naturally. Therefore, I have a simple SQL table to store the data: {id, parentid, data1, ..., dataN}

I want to be able to "zoom in" on the data and produce a report which summarizes the data found below the current branch.
That is, when standing in the root, I want to have the totals of all the data. When I have traveled down a certain branch of the tree, I want to only have the summation of the data found only for that node and its child nodes.

How do I write such a query in SQL?

Thanks in advance!

/John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `sqlite` does not support `CONNECT BY`, you will not be able to perform this calculation in a single query unless you use [nested sets or materialized paths](http://www.rampant-books.com/art_vadim_nested_sets_sql_trees.htm) for your data.

Alternatively, do it "the hard way" and traverse your tree recursively, one query for each child node starting at the parent-of-interest.

Also see:

- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
- [Recursive Hierarchies: The Relational Taboo!](http://www.kamfonas.com/id3.html)

Comment: I was thinking about traversing the children recursively but was hoping for an out-of-the-box solution by SQL.
After having read about Materialized paths I immediately felt that that would be a perfect fit for my problem! It will be trivial to implement :-) Thanks!  
/John

Answer (score 1):

Vlad's reference on nested sets looks pretty good. If you want something that covers trees and hierarchies in more detail then you can also check out [Joe Celko's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202).

The "ID, ParentID" adjacency list model is really an "old time" way of looking at hierarchies in a relational database model.